# Grunt install error/s: "should be installed with -g"

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying to install Grunt on my machine. I have read some [tutorials](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/29/get-up-running-grunt/) and followed the [installation docs](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started), but I can't get it working.

The CLI installs ok using this command:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

When I select a local directory (containing the package.json and Gruntfile) and `npm install`, I see the following message:

```
npm WARN prefer global grunt-cli@0.1.9 should be installed with -g
```

Why is this happening? I did install with `-g` - meaning 'globally', I understand.

After this, it seems that I cannot run grunt, eg:

```
$ grunt
-bash: grunt: command not found
$ grunt --version
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

How can I fix this? What am I missing?

Here is my full log:

```
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
/Users/tonyMac/.node/bin/grunt -> /Users/tonyMac/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.10 /Users/tonyMac/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
└── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1, glob@3.1.21)
Tonys-iMac:~ tonyMac$ cd projects/testingGrunt
Tonys-iMac:testingGrunt tonyMac$ npm install
npm WARN prefer global grunt-cli@0.1.9 should be installed with -g
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `sudo` to install package.

If you use `sudo` something went wrong when you installed node and npm.

I see that you use OSX so, trust me, install node with brew packet manager (http://brew.sh) and make it handle node and npm for you.

Remove node first and then just install Brew following the instruction.
Then you can just type `brew install node` and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks oozic! I removed node and re-installed with brew (good stuff!). I tried running grunt again, but unfortunately I get some errors like: `ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink` and `Run command as admin`. Does this sound right? I could provide some more code.

Comment: Well, are you using an admin account for your machine or you have an account with some restriction?

Comment: I have administrative rights, this is the only user account. Perhaps there is a read/write restriction on a certain file/directory?

Comment: I don't know the entire history of your installation. It's a bit hard, try <code>brew doctor</code> and see if there are some errors. At least you can try to delete all node/npm binaries and re-install it from brew.

Comment: Thanks oozic, I do appreciate this and how it can be difficult. Why do we need to delete al node/npm binaries, I done that prior to installing brew? I have no errors with `brew doctor`, also updated brew. The only error I see is Xcode being outdated (4.5.1), I will update this and hope it works. Man, I just want to check out grunt.

Comment: Yeah I know but it's pretty hard to troubleshoot :D

Answer (score 1):

When you install your locale packages `npm install`, it's possible a package request `grunt-cli` as a dependency. Don't worry about it, this warning don't mean it broke anything.

The `grunt: command not found` mean that the grunt binary is not added to your Path. Add it and you'll be fine: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

The path to add should be this one from the output of your terminal: `/Users/tonyMac/.node/bin`

In Bash: `PATH=$PATH:/Users/tonyMac/.node/bin` (if you run it in command line, then add `export` command before).

Comment: Thank you Simon - so is this command correct?
`export PATH=~/opt/bin:$/Users/tonyMac/.node/bin`

Comment: There shouldn't be a `$`

Comment: (Selecting a project folder), I ran that and then `npm install`. This returns `-bash: npm: command not found`. I don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: You override the full path, not extends it.

Comment: Edited my answer with details with how to extend the PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I get the same error though after `npm install`?

Comment: If you override your paths previously... well you'll need to readd every defaults path to those... Seriously, Google a bit, you should know your OS is working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it. I'm just trying to get Grunt installed here; I will search more about my os.

Comment: Yeah, because Grunt is installed and all. The problem is that your OS is not configured correctly to work with node.js - The main point is the PATH variable and how this variable load the binary, this is what you need to search and understand.

Comment: I believe that the advice to edit your PATH is a bad idea. The original problem is that `sudo` was used to install the npm package, which uses admin permissions which explains why it is inaccessible to you when running under your normal permissions. Editing your PATH is putting a band-aid on it, but the correct fix would be to undo what was originally done with `sudo` and redo it without `sudo`.