# Error with npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs

im trying to set up node on my machine.... installed npm and grunt-cli with -g at root and when i run npm install inside my code directory i get the following error

```
sudo npm install
npm WARN prefer global grunt-cli@0.1.13 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires resolve@'~0.7.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/resolve,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires through2@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/through2,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config requires mout@'~0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires async@'~0.2.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.22
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires lru-cache@'~2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/lru-cache,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires request@'~2.27.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.42.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires mkdirp@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip requires nopt@'~2.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/nopt,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.10.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires async@'^0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.22
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires chalk@'^0.5.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires inquirer@'^0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires lru-cache@'~2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/lru-cache,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires request@'~2.27.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.42.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires mkdirp@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip requires nopt@'~2.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/nopt,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires chalk@'^0.5.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires inquirer@'^0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.1
bhavan@bhavan-Inspiron-N5010:~/oyo/website$ sudo npm install
npm WARN prefer global grunt-cli@0.1.13 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires resolve@'~0.7.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/resolve,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify requires through2@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-browserify/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/through2,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config requires mout@'~0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires async@'~0.2.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.22
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires lru-cache@'~2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/lru-cache,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires request@'~2.27.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.42.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires mkdirp@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip requires nopt@'~2.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/nopt,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.10.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires async@'^0.9.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.22
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires chalk@'^0.5.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires inquirer@'^0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bower-task/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-json requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires graceful-fs@'~2.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires lru-cache@'~2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/lru-cache,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires request@'~2.27.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.42.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires mkdirp@'~0.3.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip requires nopt@'~2.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/nopt,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires chalk@'^0.5.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight requires inquirer@'^0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/bhavan/oyo/website/node_modules/grunt-bowercopy/node_modules/bower/node_modules/inquirer,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.1
er code here
```

Comment: Can you post your Node and NPM version #'s and your package.json, please?

Comment: have you installed ''' sudo apt-get install nodejs ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt install error/s: "should be installed with -g"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778249/grunt-install-error-s-should-be-installed-with-g)

Comment: Also, about [unmet dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies).

Comment: As a rule, you don't do npm install as root.  Not sure that's impacting you here, but I've always done it as a service account user, or a logged in user.

Answer (score 4):

On my system this was a result of an improperly installed package (install was aborted partway through).

In my case, all `npm WARN unmet dependency /path/node_modules/package/` messages referred to the same package, so I deleted that package from my node_modules directory and reinstalled it. This resolved all of the issues that I was having. (npm spouted this error even when trying to install packages which did not depend on the problematic package, and this still resolved the issue)

In your case, several packages are listed, so:

- Remove your Node modules directory

  ```
  rm -r node-modules
  ```
- Reinstall your packages

  ```
  npm install
  ```
- If the package that you tried install is still not installed, reinstall it.

  ```
  npm install --save package
  ```

For others encountering this issue, if the package you are trying to install is global, you may have to remove your global `node_modules` directory instead. `npm ls -g --depth 0` will tell you the location of your global `node_modules` directory as well as give you a list of installed packages. Take note of these because you'll need to manually reinstall them.